# how to input string into specific memory

Tags: mips

working on a problem that goes like this:

write a program that will prompt user to input 3 numbers that don't exceed 6(commas can't be stored as string) digits. The numbers must be stored in memory as null terminated strings the first number must be stored in memory address 0x10000000. The second number must be stored in memory address 0x10000008. The third number must be stored in memory address 0x10000010.

this is what I wrote, but I keep getting a syntax error on line 14 which is weird because it looks fine. how will I know if the string being inputted is in the right memory address?

```
.globl main

.data
prompt1: .asciiz "Enter first number:"
prompt2: .asciiz "Enter second number:"
prompt3: .asciiz "Enter third number:"

.text
#0x10000000 stores first number
#0x10000008 stores second number
#0x10000010 stores third number

main:
#printing prompt1
li $v0, 4          #line 14 where syntax error happens
la $a0, prompt1
syscall

lui $s0, 0x1000   # get address into $s0


#input first number 
li $v0, 8
la $a0, 0($s0)         #reads number into memory(0x10000000)
li $a1,8               #7 characters
syscall

#prinitng prompt2
li $v0,4
la $a0, prompt2
syscall

#input second number
li $v0,8
la $a0,8($s0)     #reads number into memory 0x10000008
li $a1,8
syscall

#printing prompt3
li $v0,4
la $a0,prompt3
syscall

#inputting third number
li $v0,8
la $a0, 10($s0)       #reads number into memory 0x10000010
li $a1, 8             #7 characters
syscall
```

Comment: *I get a syntax error* is meaningless unless you tell us what that synax error is specifically. It's on the screen right in front of you, but unfortunately we can't see your screen from here, so you'll need to [edit] your question and include it yourself. If you want help, include the relevant information in your post.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you are running your program in spim -bare mode.  This means that pseudo-instructions such as li, la and others will not work. Pseudo-Instructions are not real mips instructions.  If you are going to run in spim -bare mode you must rework your code and get rid of those pseudo-instructions.